# Parenthetical "read out loud" for word substitution

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I want the reader to see the word *A*, but read it as *B*. Or, to put it another way, I would like the reader to read *A* while thinking at its true meaning *B*.

I think I can accomplish this generally by:

*If you have an *A* (read out loud *B*), you should…*

A specific example could be:

*If you have a chihuahua (read out loud, a small dog), you should…*

Is the expression ‘(read out loud, *word substitute*)’ correct?

Comment: Can't you say "If you have an A (read B)(pronounced B), you should…"? "If you have a chihuahua (read yappy, snappy pooch), ..."

Comment: *B* is supposed to be the definition, not other examples. Would that still apply? I've just updated my question with my true intention.

Comment: is your question about the expression “read out loud”?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why someone would vote negatively on this question. I'm not a native speaker and therefore I'm unsure about the correct usage of the language.

Comment: I'd usually use "A (read B)" only ironically. We say A, but lemme tell you we all mean B, right? B is not an example, but a restating of what A really is.

Comment: @user66974 I believe this is the form I saw in a book. I'm wondering if it is correct / I remember it correctly.

Comment: As for downvotes, don't take it personally. Standards are very high here. However, you cannot politely ask who or why. Just saying.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, there is no ‘out loud’ part. I also understand this is an informal form and it is not documented in a grammar of sort, yes?

Comment: It's normally written as either "(read B)" or "(think B)", and they mean the same thing. I've never seen "out loud".

Comment: Yuo could write "(said as B)" if A is a word that's unacceptable in formal contexts, while B is an acceptable euphemism.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. The full context is: *A* is a specific type of *B*. What I'm stating applies to *B*, but I'm currently writing about *A*. I thought I recalled the ‘out loud’ bit, but I guess I was mistaken. Can someone write an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Would this not be better placed in SE Writing? Either way, I suggest any useful Answer could take a whole chapter somewhere…

I'm sorry to say, the exposition seems too far from reality to have a useful meaning. Wanting the reader to see the word A, but read it as B seems like a very strange thing and doubly so in SE ELU…

To put it another way, you as writer might use a phrase like 'for politician, read (clown/dissembler/self-seeker)…' but does that sound like what you're describing?